# Regression model for testing the difference between the groups in presence of the covariate

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, ancova, robust-standard-error

I have a regression model like this

```
lm(ContiniousVariable ~ ContiniousCovariate + BinaryCategoricalVariable)
```

I repeat this model for each of the 20 ContiniousVariables. I want to see whether there are differences between the two groups (represented in BinaryCategoricalVariable) for each of those 20 dependent variables.

I am not interested in accuracy of the model as the whole, just whether the difference between the groups is significant in the presence of the single covariate.

Since there is heteroscedasticity in residuals for almost all of the ContinousVariables I employed robust standard errors (HC3). The residuals are not normally distributed tough the shape of distribution always resembles normal distribution (i.e. it isn't heavily skewed).

My sample is relatively large (group1=750, group2=300).

**Question:** is the model I employ proper enough to test the differences between the groups in the presence of the covariate?

I am preparing a paper and I am concerned violation of assumptions may be a problem for some reviewers.